# Why i don't receive update notifications

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

I was previous a Kubuntu user but installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS for a week now and I always need to open update manager manually and search.
If they're are any updates,because I don't get any notifications, I tried reinstalling update-manager and update-notifier and still no updates notifications.

On Kubuntu I always received update notifications after most 1 minute after i start my pc.

Why is that and how can i fix it?

Comment: oh damn i forgot to set Display immediately on "other updates" tough it doesn't display every time when security updates are available either.

Answer (score 0):

Check Settings in Update-manager, and choose `Daily` at **Automatic Check for Updates**. Perhaps your's current is Never? Try it.

Comment: "Oh damn i forgot to set Display immediately on "other updates" tough it doesn't display every time when security updates are available either." it was set only for security updates, don't know why.If you would read my comment you wouldn't been needed to write this "answer".